# Firestore add method does not work properly when I am offline

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

If I run the following line of code when my device is offline, The `card` will be added to local cache. But the application never goes to the next line.

```
const data = await firebase.firestore().collection('cards').add(card);
console.log(data) // this line never get executed!
```

Comment: What is local cash? Maybe you meant local cache?

Comment: @romin21 yes it was a typo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write methods (such as `add()`) return a promise that fulfills once the write operation has been completed (or rejected) on the server. Since you're not connected to the server, that never happens and thus your `await` will stay blocked.

Note that you don't need to `await` for the local write operation, as the write to the local cache happens synchronously. So as soon as the `add(...)` call returns (and doesn't raise an exception), you can be sure that the write was completed to the local cache. Hence, you should only use `await` if you need to know that the write was also handled by the server, in which case the behavior you see is exactly what you'll want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So how can I find if my data has been written to local storage or on the server?

Comment: If there is a problem writing the data to the local disk, an exception will be throw. So if  the line with `add(...)` runs without throwing an exception, the write has been written to the local cache.

Comment: How can we catch errors when writing to server when the device goes back online?